# Ubuntu-TV app development

Tags: ubuntu-tv

Are there guides/wikis on how to get started with Ubuntu TV app development?
Are there existing apps out there, I have only seen YouTube.

I have some experience working with BOXEE apps and was wondering if its similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Ubuntu TV site *(Contributor's page)*](http://www.ubuntu.com/tv/contributors)

> ***Get Involved***
>
> If you’d like to get involved with the ongoing development of Ubuntu
>   TV, you’ll find yourself welcome and among friends who share a passion
>   for classy entertainment experiences. For more general information on
>   contributing to Ubuntu projects, [visit the Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuTV/Contributing).
>
> Code contributions to Ubuntu TV follow the same process as the Unity
>   project. [Learn more about the process](http://www.canonical.com/contributors) ›
>
> ***Communicating with other contributors***
>
> The Ubuntu TV team uses email and IRC to keep in touch, plan work and
>   manage releases. Start with [the team Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntutv), where you
>   can join our mailing list. There’s a fair amount of traffic, but it’s
>   all signal! For real-time interaction, hop on to the #ubuntu-tv IRC
>   channel on Freenode.

Take a look at the [Ubuntu TV site *(Contributor's page)*](http://www.ubuntu.com/tv/contributors) for more details on this.